# Getting error in the php file on test server but no errors in localhost

Tags: php, mysql, localhost

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT id, username, firstname,lastname, country, trade FROM myMembers WHERE email_activated='1' ORDER BY id ASC"); 
$sql2 = mysql_query("SELECT id, username, firstname,lastname, country, trade FROM mymembers WHERE email_activated='1' ORDER BY id DESC $limit"); 
$paginationDisplay = ""; 
if ($lastPage != "1"){
$paginationDisplay .= 'Page <strong>' . $pn . '</strong> of ' . $lastPage. '<img      src="images/clearImage.gif" width="48" height="1" alt="Spacer" />';
if ($pn != 1) {
$previous = $pn - 1;
$paginationDisplay .=  '&nbsp;  <a href="' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . '?pn=' . $previous . '"> Back</a> ';
} 
$paginationDisplay .= '<span class="paginationNumbers">' . $centerPages . '</span>';
if ($pn != $lastPage) {
$nextPage = $pn + 1;
$paginationDisplay .=  '&nbsp;  <a href="' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . '?pn=' .$nextPage    . '"> Next</a> ';} }
$outputList = '';
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql2)) { $id = $row["id"];
$username = $row["username"];
$firstname = $row["firstname"];
$lastname = $row["lastname"];
$country = $row["country"];
$trade=$row["trade"];
$check_pic = "members/$id/image01.jpg";
$default_pic = "members/0/image02.jpg";
if (file_exists($check_pic)) {
$user_pic = "<img src="$check_pic" width="150px"; height="150px";  />";     } else {
$user_pic = "<img src="$default_pic" width="150px" height="150px";  />"; // forces    default picture to be 120px wide and no more}
$name=$firstname.' '.$lastname; 
$outputList .= '<div id="content" class="clearfix"><section id="left"><div       id="userStats class="clearfix"><div class="pic">
<a href="profile.php?id=' . $id . '" target="_self">' . $user_pic . '</a></div><div   class="data">
<h1><a href="profile.php?id=' . $id . '" target="_self">' . $name. '</a></h1>
<h3>From: ' . $country .'<h3>
<h3>Trade: ' . $trade .'<h3>
<h3>Username: ' . $username .'</h3>
<div class="sep"></div>
<ul class="numbers clearfix">
<li><a href="profile.php?id=' . $id . '" target="_self">Full Profile</a></li>
<li><a href="info.php?id=' . $id . '" target="_self">About</a></li>
<li><a href="blab.php?id=' . $id . '" target="_self">WhiteBoard</a></li>
</ul></div></div></section></div><br>';}
```

This code works in the localhost but is not working in the deployed server.

This is the page user is directed after the login. The error on the server is this:
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE in /home/u576778821/public_html/interact/index.php on line 119

where the 119 line is this

```
    $user_pic = "<img src="$check_pic" width="150px"; height="150px";  />";
```

And for now I am using free azuka.biz server.

Comment: You're sure this was working on localhost? The concatenation error should have thrown an error on localhost as well

Comment: yes that was working in localhost mate...Idk how

Answer (score 1, accepted):

watch the quotes it should be

```
$user_pic = "<img src=\"$check_pic\" width=\"150px\" height=\"150px\"  />";
```

or

```
$user_pic = "<img src='".$check_pic."' width='150px' height='150px'  />";
```

Edit,

**watch semicolons after width and height. They shouldnt be there**

Comment: yah that the case but the semi colons are required sir

Comment: now my code is working fine with semi-colons the only change required was the width, height, etc were not escaped properly

Comment: @hritikwatts, semi colons shouldnt be there, browser is intelligent to cut that off, but putting semicolon after `width="150px" and height="150px"` is syntax error. May be all browser are not intelligent to rip that semicolons.

Comment: okay so I shall remove the semi-colons now and check. Testing now

Comment: Getting this error..
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '}' in C:\xampp\htdocs\Fluid Solution\minified\interact\index.php on line 120

I think you misunderstood because this code is inside php tags and it is used to define value of a variable so semi-colon is needed

Comment: @hritikwatts, `width="150px";` i meant this semicolon is not needed. Its a string not a variable, you already have a semicolon at the end of the statement `$user_pic="<input ..... />";`

what is on line 120?

Comment: closing of if and starting of else{

Comment: @hritikwatts, give me line 119 the one you were getting error and you've updated. Let me see what change you've made to this line

Comment: I told you the line is    }else{//thats it 

in my original post the line is
$user_pic = "<img src="$check_pic" width="150px"; height="150px";  />";     } else {

Answer (score 2):

Try this,

```
$user_pic = "<img src='".$check_pic."' width="150px" height="150px"  />";
```

or

```
$user_pic = '<img src="'.$check_pic.'" width="150px" height="150px" >';
```

Comment: but sir the code is working fine in localhost and I am goin to try the code you suggested now

Comment: still it will not work. there is still double quotes in width and height...and the whole string is double quoted.

Comment: okay that was the problem in two lines the double quotes were not escaped but I am wondering why the code was working in the localhost. Any ideas sir.

Comment: @hritikwatts, why you have semicolons after `width="150px"` and `height="150px"`?? It shouldnt be there

Comment: but now the code is working fine with the semi-colons the only change was to escape the double quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Transform your line 119 to:

```
$user_pic = "<img src='".$check_pic."' width='150px' height='150px' />";
```

The dots (.) before and after $check_pic means that you perform string concatenation.

Comment: semi colons shouldnt be there after width and height